# How to append Named Entites extracted from DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, spacy, named-entity-recognition

the following code to extract and then print entities from `df['Article']` is working just fine.

```
for i in df['Article'].to_list():
    doc = nlp(i)
    for entity in doc.ents:
        print((entity.text))
```

But whenever I try to `append` these entities using `entities_list.append((entity.text))` I get `TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()` error I have tried to create `entities_list=[]` using following way

```
entities_list = []
for i in df['Article'].to_list():
    doc = nlp(i)
    for entity in doc.ents:
        print((entity.text))
```

As well as

```
for i in df['Article'].to_list():
    entities_list = []
    doc = nlp(i)
    for entity in doc.ents:
        print((entity.text))
```

Also even if I try to create another DataFrame or add new column to `df` I get same error. Can someone help with what am I doing wrong here? Thank you

EDIT:
data in `df['Articles']` is news text like

> Pence’s move comes as inoculation efforts are unfurling around the
> world in the race to halt a pandemic that has claimed at least 1.66
> million lives and infected more than 74 million people.

very first code prints entities extracted from text but I need those entities to append in list like as following

```
[entity1, entity2, entity3, entity4]
```

Comment: Where is `entities_list` in your code example? Please add an small, but meaningful, input sample and the expected output to better understand the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Dani Mesejo I have added more information to question, please have a look.

Comment: Do you have missing values (NAN) in the column df['Articles']? Try doing something like `for i in df['Article'].fillna('').to_list()`

Comment: Thank you @Dani Mesejo this has solved the error kindly add it to answer so I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the column *Article* has some missing values, do the following:

```
entities_list = []
for i in df['Article'].fillna('').to_list():
    doc = nlp(i)
    for entity in doc.ents:
        entities_list.append((entity.text))
```